# Converting date string (YYYY-MM-DD) to datetime object pymongo

Tags: mongodb, datetime, pymongo-3.x

Before mass inserting using insertmany(), I need to change the "Date" field of  each document from a string which is in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD' (for example '2020-02-28) to a datetime object which can be used in mongo for later purposes...

Is there a possible way of doing this using pymongo

So my idea would look something like this

```
dict["Date"] = Mongo_Date(dict["Date"]) #converting the original string to a date object
outputList.append(dict)

#Later on in code
mycol.insert_many(outputList)
```

is there any easy way of doing this with pymongo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities come to mind:

- use the python `map` function to modify all of the objects at once
- insert the objects into MongoDB, and then use update with $dateFromString to modify them